# ASP.MVC Need a good pattern for handling new DB requests from website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a couple of Windows services that run on a 5 minute time, check the database for any new Queue requests that haven't been processed.

If so, it will process the request.

But I'm tired of using Windows services and want everything to be handled via the website as close to real time as possible. So I made a controller to add requests with.

```
public ViewResult Add(string url)
{
     using(var db = new dbEntity())
     {
        Queue q = new Queue();
        q.url = url;
        q.processed = false;
        db.Queues.Add(q);
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Now I'd like to have something trigger the action of processing the queue if it isn't already running. This is the part that confusing me, I still stuck thinking Windows services I guess. Is there away to have some kind of Process running in another thread in the App Pool dedicated to processing a queue?

If so, how would I go about doing this?

And if you think there's a better way I could be doing this entire process I'd like to hear that too.

Thanks

Comment: Built-in dashboard.. sweet. Why not make this the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible approaches is to use the hangfire library.

http://hangfire.io

It's quite mature, has a built-in dashboard and seems it does what you need.